# How much disk usage do RAW videos use?

Tags: video, disk-space

How much space does RAW video footage ( downloaded directly from the camera ) use?

I use a Sony Handicam dcr-hc51e.

Comment: About half the size of the disk, sometimes more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends entirely on what format and resolution the camera uses.

As far as I can see, with a DV camera like that you get 36 megabit/s.

Answer (score 1):

I made a small utility that could maybe help you out with disk space calculation, it is available as a simple javascript here:

http://www.videophill.com/blog/?p=54